# Ubuntu 12.10 wont install from hard drive after reboot prompt

Tags: 12.10, wubi, installation

After downloading Ubuntu 12.10 and using the Wubi option to install through windows 7 I hit a road block. I partitioned the `C:` drive to install Linux and did the primary install no worries.

But, after I get the prompt to reboot, which I do, I choose Ubuntu and the installation starts just fine. It loads to the point of *"copying files"* and the progress bar moves along to approximately 2/3 but that's it. It freezes there for around 30mins and then the spinning mouse stops and I'm locked out all together. Nothing works. I have to hold down the off button and force a shutdown.

I'm doing this on a newly purchased Toshiba Satellite P875D with 16Gb RAM, 640Gb HHD and an AMD A8 4500 x64 quad core processor. I split the partition giving Linux 50Gb of space which is more than enough.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this problem? I shouldn't have to burn a CD or create a USB to boot from with Wubi but I will if this is where everything is going wrong.

Comment: just for info, for wubi you don't need to create partition. But that isn't the problem here.

Comment: Please double-check if the files are ok. Download again or run some checksumming tool. I don't know about these automagic from-windowsland installers, but some install CDs used to have a boot option to check the state of the CD.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I know I didn't need to create a partition I just wanted to so I wouldn't have to ever worry about windows crapping out and not being able to boot.
I've checked and re-checked. All files seem to be ok. DL was from both Ubuntu (with their wubi option) and torrent just to make sure there wasn't an interruption anywhere.
Also, if there was a file issue wouldn't it have been picked up earlier? I mean, copying files is the last process in the installation after all.
Thanks to the both of you for your input none the less :)